# Bad positioning with md-input in Chrome - Angular Material & HTML

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, angular-material

I have an `ng-repeat` with a `layut="row"` containing an `md-input`, an icon and a button, there is also a spinner but that is not going to be shown when the button is shown and vice versa.

I have been experiencing some bad positioning with these rows in Chrome. I have no idea why it does this and how to fix it? Have someone else experienced this bug? Here are some screenshots and below is my html.

Also, I cannot scroll the md-content in firefox, while it works in chrome.. that is also a bug I have not solved yet. So if someone knows the solution for that that would be a bonus :) Thanks!

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: FireFox]

My html:

```
<md-content class="darkgrey-bkgr white-text" flex layout="column" layout-margin>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="start start" ng-repeat="(id, doc) in ctrl.params" layout-margin flex="100">
    <md-input-container flex>
      <label>Parameter {{id}}</label>
      <input ng-model="doc.value">
    </md-input-container>
    <i class="material-icons">
      code
      <md-tooltip md-direction="right">
        {{doc.formattedValue}}
      </md-tooltip>
    </i>
    <md-progress-circular class="small-config-spinner" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button md-fab md-mini md-primary" ng-click="ctrl.updateConfigParameter(id,doc.value)">
      <i class="material-icons white-text">check</i>
    </md-button>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: can u put in ur code in fiddle?

Comment: did you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a parent `div` element to get the desired result.

```
<div layout="column" flex>
     //Your Code
</div>
```

Its wokring fine in Chrome and Firefox
Here is the working example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/MeJWpd